# Vue3 reactive counter to setup

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make the counter data be transmitted after clicking in the setup, but it doesn't work, what's wrong? Thanks.

```
setup(props) {
    let count = ref(1)
    let obj = reactive({ count })
    let form = reactive({
        name: props.user.name,
        count: obj.count,
 })
return { form, count, obj }
```

I change count by:

```
@click="count++"
```

And after click data in setup(props) dont update, **BUT** if i write like as is, it has been reactive:

```
setup(props) {
    let count = ref(1)
    let obj = reactive({ count })
    let form = reactive({
        name: props.user.name,
        count: obj,
 })
return { form, count, obj }
```

And after click count: obj will be update, but as it should be the data is passed as an object:

```
{"count":3}
```

Why if I try to use `obj.count` doesn't work dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

##### it's because when you access the `ref` from inside the `reactive` to assign it to a value it gets the value only, and the reactivity is lost.

here is an [example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1kk1uwyAQha8yYpNEcUDeuk7U3oONQ3Ft1xgEOK1kcfcO+Ce1qm4wzHx+M7xhIm/G0McoSUFKJ2xr/I0PAK0y2nqYwMo6w6USvn1ICFBbreCAPxxe+BBJ+Z3Id1lXY++nGAJw0o/maKw27gRLDKCXHoQeBw/XqHvMT78z+t6l+FzqOC1o2EG1tmpHrUmY8SLK0LTNnimMpcQaeWpabNQOeM8onM0aWWolzEj64FKyzR08eKlMX3mZvCqbHF5F34rPKydJ4Xzm5DZtNwgla/K/6Nbpiqey/8Cxvz2drNjwkm09kYzM47uoytDO6QGHm4ziS8JxUqxj4QSHGc+cNN4bVzDmahGfROeoth8Md9Ri3VZJKp263K3+ctKiMCeLOYGEH/Cxveg=)

```html
<script>
  import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';

  export default{
    setup(props) {
      let count = ref(1)
      let obj = reactive({ count })
      let form = reactive({
        count: obj.count,
        obj: obj
      })
      return { form, count, obj }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <h1 @click="count++">{{ count }}</h1>
  <h1 @click="obj.count++">{{ obj }}</h1>
  <h1 @click="form.count++">{{ form }}</h1>
</template>
```

If you click on `@click="count++"`, the `count`, `obj.count` and `form.obj.count` are updated, but the `form.count` isn't.

It may not be immediately clear, but when you assign `obj.count` to `form.count`, it is not the `ref` that is passed. Instead the value is resolved, and that is assigned to the value and the reactivity is lost. You can look into the [advanced reactivity](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#shallowreactive) for some other options. For example, if you use `shallowReactive` like: `let obj = shallowReactive({ count: count })`, then the count will remain reactive, but you will need to update the shallowRef with `obj.count.value++` instead of `obj.count++`

[example 2](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1Uk1zgyAQ/Ss7XJJMDE6u1mTav9AzF2OxakEYQNMZh//eBcX0Y3rBZd++t+tbZvKiNZ1GTgpS2tp02l3ZANBJrYyDGQxvMjyq2nUTz8C2lRDq/hqyW7yA4KExSsIO1XZPbAgy/DPKvPGmGoWbQwrAcjfqvTZK2wOsOQDBHdRqHBxcQtP9+YAaD0jdegR+tdzPC6VYmf4np1FGRrVUnUBINFSlMcweEOYikDLfRA1ObgZ0JShni0gWR/NrjQ8fPMp8MxMvjkstKsejtWV7hudadPXHhZEocTwycp3XfwHvy7w9/y3dZqVTJUaeSLH7P5Qw5sJJ1dGSrbzMt8lIRpadn2SlaW/VgC8iGsZWwDJSpHUxgksOd0Za57Qt8tw2dXhHvaXKvOcYUYN9O8kpt/J0M+puuUFhRlaLPPFficzRWA==)

```html
<script>
  import { ref, reactive, shallowRef, shallowReactive } from 'vue';

  export default{
    setup(props) {
      let count = ref(1);
      let obj = shallowReactive({ count: count });
      let form = reactive({
        count: obj.count,
        obj: obj
      });
      return { form, count, obj };
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <h1 @click="count++">{{ count }}</h1>
  <h1 @click="obj.count.value++">{{ obj }}</h1>
  <h1 @click="form.count++">{{ form }}</h1>
</template>
```